# textView.setText(); crashes

Tags: android, debugging, null, return, settext

The setText() method returns null in my application why?

```
public class GetValue extends Activity {
    char letter = 'g';
    int ascii = letter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
            textView.setText(ascii);
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter what text i put in, it crashes anyway. Why does setText() keep returning null?

Thank you, in advance

**Solution:** My error was in the xml file. I wrote:
android:text="@+id/txt_1"
When it should say:
android:id="@+id/txt_1"

Thanks a lot for all the answers and comments!

Comment: are you sure, that textView isn't null already? Could you provide an error message?

Comment: Probably findViewById() isn't working. Are you sure you defined a TextView called txt_1?

Comment: post your main.xml file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You tried to pass an integer as parameter to setText, which assumes it is a resource ID. To display computed text, pass it as a string: `textView.setText("g");`

Edited: Check your XML file, I have test with something very basic and it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="myTextView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe try to clean your project (Project->Clean in Eclipse), I recently have some trouble with R generation on the last ADT version.

Comment: I have tried to put in plane text. The only thing i know is that the setText() line makes my program crash. I know it's nothing wrong with my xml file. The logcat says that textView variable returns null. I think i am using the setText() method wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
textView.setText(Integer.toString(ascii));
```

Also make sure that your layout xml has TextView txt_1

Answer (score 2):

I've tried :

```
Integer.toString(char) and String.valueOf(char)
```

both didnt work.
The only solution is :

```
txt.setText(""+char);
```

This is not very efficient from optimization point of view but it does the trick :)